# Find occurrences with regular expression (Java engine)

Tags: java, regex

I would like to use some regular expression to find occurrences. For e.g, users will enter:

**word1 code1 -10001** !**none**

which mean: search word1 AND code1 AND -10001 AND NOT none

These criterion are used to build a regexp.

I have such text lines:

1 - "My usual word12 is including GCode10 -10001. End of record"  // This should be true and return "world12 is including GCode10 -10001."

2 - "This is an other line word12 is including GCode10 -10001 none  End of record" // This should be false and return nothing

I tried this:

```
^(?=.*?word1)(?=.*?code1)(?=.*?-10001)((?!none).)*$
```

It works for line 1, but it return all the line

I also tried this:

```
(\\w*word1\\w*).*(\\w*code1\\w*).*(\\w*-10001\\w*)(?!none)
```

But it gave me only "word12", "GCode10", but it missed "-10001" and moreover, it match for the second line! It shouldn't.

I'm not an expert in regexp...

Comment: `logged` wasn't mentioned in your question but you seem to be using in your regex using negative lookahead.

Comment: Have you thought of using a plain loop to check for these things?  what if the user types `word*` ?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Currently, it will be include in the regex pattern, so it will retrieve the occurrence 0 or n time... I have to put \ in front of it

Comment: Like `word\*` ? Personally I wouldn't use a regular expression as it would be simpler and more likely to work IMHO.

Comment: Tim gave me the answer for these cases: Pattern.quote()...

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, you just used the negative lookahead incorrectly:

```
^(?=.*?word1)(?=.*?code1)(?=.*?-10001)(?!.*?none).*$
```

You also should be compiling the regex with the multiline option unless you're treating each line as a separate string. So, if `subjectString` is a multiline string,

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*?word1)(?=.*?code1)(?=.*?-10001)(?!.*?none).*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

will give you a list of all the lines that fulfill your criteria.

If you're dealing with user input, you might want to call `Pattern.quote()` on all the strings your users give you, so any regex metacharacters will be escaped.

Comment: Yes it works, BUT it retrieves all the line. I would like only items from first to last occurrences. In the example I gave, it will also retrieve "My usual...."

Comment: Thanks for the "Pattern.quote()", I didn't know that.

Comment: @Zamboo: Ah, I overlooked that. Well, that's not so easy - I expect that the allowed patterns may occur in any order? If the order isn't fixed, this won't be trivial.